# How do I get TestScheduler to tick in RxJs5?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to write a sample unit test with `Observable.interval` in RxJs version 5. I'm running the following code, but my observable only fires once, not 20 times, as anticipated.

```
it('does its interval thing synchonously', ()=> {

        let x = [];
        let scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();
        let interval$ = Rx.Observable.interval(500, scheduler).take(20);

        interval$.subscribe(
            value => {
                x.push(value);
                console.log(value)
            },
        );

        for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            scheduler.flush();
        }

        expect(x.length).toBe(20);

    });
```

How do I make my `TestScheduler` move the Observable forward by 10000 milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that the `TestScheduler` is intended to be used with [marble testing](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md) and works with observables composed from those returned by its [`createColdObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.2/src/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L38) and [`createHotObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.2/src/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L51) methods.

Instead, you could use the [`VirtualTimeScheduler`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/scheduler/VirtualTimeScheduler.ts) - upon which the `TestScheduler` is based:

```js
let scheduler = new Rx.VirtualTimeScheduler();
let interval$ = Rx.Observable.interval(500, scheduler).take(20);

let values = [];
interval$.subscribe(value => values.push(value));

scheduler.flush();
console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Note that only a single `flush` call is required.